# Can't find my NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a NullPointerException that I just can't see. I know it's probably something simple that I'm overlooking. I have bit that reads in a text file line by line splits it, and uses the data to create a custom class and pass the data off to be added to a SQLite database.

```
Public void createData() {
try {
        InputStream in = this.getAssets().open("stops.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        line=reader.readLine();
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
            String lineValues[] = line.split(",");
            Stops stop = new Stops();
            stop.setLon(lineValues[5]);
            stop.setLat(lineValues[4]);
            stop.setName(lineValues[2]);
            stop.setNumber(lineValues[0]);
            dataSource.create(stop);
        }

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NullPointerException n) {
        n.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG,n.toString());
    }
 }
```

The exception is occurring on the `dataSource.create(stop);` Any tips out there?

Edit: here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ccalgary.transit.helper/ccalgary.transit.helper.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ccalgary.transit.helper.MainActivity.createData(MainActivity.java:341)
    at ccalgary.transit.helper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
```

and here is the onCreate

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sContext = getApplicationContext();
    boolean boot = settings.getBoolean("launch", false);
    if (boot == false) {
        createData();
    }
    dataSource = new StopsDataSource(this);
    dbhelper = new StopsDBHelper(this,TABLE_STOPS,null,1);
    mDatabase = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dataSource.open();
    if (mDatabase.isOpen()) {

        Log.d(TAG, "database open");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"database closed");
    }
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        //Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
    }
    //MyLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();



    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
```

Data source:

```
public class StopsDataSource {

SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase database;

public StopsDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new StopsDBHelper(context, "stops", null, 1 );

}

public void open() {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public Stops create(Stops stops) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(StopsDBHelper.COLUMN_STOP_LAT, stops.getLat());
    values.put(StopsDBHelper.COLUMN_STOP_LON, stops.getLon());
    values.put(StopsDBHelper.COLUMN_STOP_NAME, stops.getName());
    values.put(StopsDBHelper.COLUMN_STOP_NUMBER,stops.getNumber());
    long instertID = database.insert(StopsDBHelper.TABLE_STOPS, null, values);
    stops.setId(instertID);
    return stops;
}

}
```

and the DB Helper:

```
public class StopsDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_STOPS = "stops";
public static final String COlUMN_ID = "stopID";
public static final String COLUMN_STOP_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_STOP_LAT = "lat";
public static final String COLUMN_STOP_LON = "lon";
public static final String COLUMN_STOP_NUMBER = "number";
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_STOPS + "(" + COlUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  COLUMN_STOP_LAT + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STOP_LON + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_STOP_NUMBER + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STOP_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
public StopsDBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STOPS);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the exception stack trace.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a stack trace?

Comment: Can you also post your onCreate?

Comment: dataSource.create(stop); dataSource is initialized in the oncreate method that I'll edit and add in here

Comment: Could you post the `dataSource.create` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method `createData()` before initializing `dataSource`. Make it before method call. ie, make initializations first before calling any function that may use it.

```
    dataSource = new StopsDataSource(this);
 if (boot == false) {
        createData();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`dataSource` is null, stop can't be null or you will get a null pointer while calling its methods, also we can see you specifically call `new Stops();`

Comment: Data source is not null, I just have it defined in the onCreate section sorry.

Comment: Provide the stack trace and we will be able to confirm that. Also, where are these statements called?